# Javascript multiple if true conditions

Tags: javascript

I neeed help with multiple `if` conditions.

`if condition 1 & condition 2 true` means I want both condition actions:

```
if(condition 1 true) {
    $('.inner_wrapper').addClass('em-border-red');
    return false;
}

if(condition 2 true) {
    $('.cCal').addClass('em-border-red');
    return false;
}

if(condition 3 true){
    $('.cCal-row2').addClass('em-border-red');
    return false;
}
```

But only one condition works.

Comment: Don't return from inside the `if` blocks?

Comment: But what's wrong with this?

Comment: If the ifs are inside a function, the control will be returned back once return statement is encountered. So place return statement at the end of the function.

Answer (score 2):

Each of your `if` blocks contains a `return` statement. As soon as one condition is met, no further code will execute. This is, by definition, the [behaviour of the `return` statement](http://es5.github.com/#x12.9):

> A return statement causes a function to cease execution and return a value to the caller

Since all of yours just return `false`, you should be able to move the `return` to after the conditions:

```
if(condition1) {
    $('.inner_wrapper').addClass('em-border-red');
}
if(condition2) {
    $('.cCal').addClass('em-border-red');
}
if(condition3) {
    $('.cCal-row2').addClass('em-border-red');
}
return false;
```

Comment: What if these statements are not the only code in the block?`

Comment: Then have a fourth statement, `if(condition1 || condition2 || condition3)` after those and return from within that? Obviously we can't give a perfect answer without greater context from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `return false;` form each if block and try to manage it at the bottom, outside of if condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
retVal = true;
if(condition 1 true)
 {
     $('.inner_wrapper').addClass('em-border-red');
     retVal = false;

 }
if(condition 2 true)
 {
    $('.cCal').addClass('em-border-red');
     retVal = false;

 }
if(condition 3 true)
 {
    $('.cCal-row2').addClass('em-border-red');
     retVal = false;

 }
return retVal;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways:

```
    <!-- and condition //-->
    if (a == b && a != c) {
        // your stuff
    <!-- or condition //-->
    } else if (a == c || a ==b) {
        // other stuff
    <!-- otherwise //-->
    } else {
        // another stuff
    }
```

Otherwise you have "switch case". Like on [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp).